# I moved wp-content in a new folder. Now the themes don't work. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I had to move wp-content folder in another folder.
While before there was:

- wp-content
- wp-admin
- wp-include
- other files

Now there is:

- myfolder (where there is wp-content)
- wp-admin
- wp-include
- other files

I did it and I edited `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` with the new directory, like this:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfolder/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/myfolder/wp-content' );
```

I also edited in wp-includes - default-constants.php like this:

```
if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR') )
        define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'public/wp-content' );

if ( !defined('WP_CONTENT_URL') )
        define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/public/wp-content');
```

Now, the contents are all shown, but the themes don't work very well. The colors are wrong, a lot of things aren't at their places, excetera...
When wp-content was in the same directory as wp-admin and wp-include all worked perfectly. Why not now?

Comment: Please show your code changes to *wp-config.php*. Also, please show your relevant directory tree.

Comment: Try `dirname(__FILE__) . '/../myfolder/wp-content`. I may have interpreted your file tree wrong. There may be paths that are now incorrect within the theme setup.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last sentence.

Comment: In your second definition, are you inputting `example` or `www.example.com`...assuming .com?

Comment: Please, don't self-duplicate your questions. There's nothing much about this, if the theme doesn't work, it probably has wp-content hard coded somewhere (ie, the author don't know we can change it in wp-config).

Comment: brasofilo, but even the default themes of wordpress don't work. How could this be possible?

mevius, I tried both.

Comment: Try moving those two definitions before: `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`

Comment: Don't edit default-constraints...

Answer (score 0):

If the content is shown, that implies that the definitions you have added to **wp-config.php** are working properly.

Incorrect styling implies that there is a hard-coded path within your theme files. For example, the theme creator used:

```
// Incorrect 
echo '/wp-content/themes/themename/css/stylesheet.css';
```

Instead of...

```
// Correct 
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet.css';
```

Or even an incorrect call to [content_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url).

You'll need to find these hard-coded URLs/paths, and update them to the correct format.

Comment: In a file named style-custom.php I have this line:

$current_url = dirname(__FILE__);

should I change it in:

$current_url = dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfolder'; ?

Comment: I did it, didn't do anything. I'm going mad.